# Get very large json file using angular http.get

Tags: angular, http

I am using angular `http.get` request to get data from server. The server is returning with a very large json object. Due to large json (which is around **20MB**), its taking me minutes to download it. Is there any way to get data in pieces? How may I speed it up?

Comment: Which data would you want in pieces? You can't just split up a json object and expect it to be valid (and fit your interface). If you have very large arrays in your json object for your view you can try to page them on the serverside to reduce the size of the overall json. You can also split the initial call to the large json object in multiple smaller calls to parts of the json object.

Comment: I was expecting to get JSON object somehow in pieces. For example: If a json object is having an array with 1000 items, then I get 250 items in each API call and these API calls are called in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

you should check out traversing via Pagination : https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/ & https://nordicapis.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-api-pagination/

In RESTful Apis you should chunk the data, and get through it via querying you paginated request, and make multiple calls, until you are done.
And the speed depends on you network. Rarely the code.
If you can lazy load and slowly update what ever you do, this is the best option. If you need all the data at Once AND fast, try a socket. But i would assume this would not help.

I assume you get a list of a lot of data, and not one Big JSON document wich is just one giant entry right ?

Comment: Thanks. Sadly the JSON object is a single giant document.